# Change in genesis file without creating chain from the start

Tags: private-blockchain, consensus, genesis

We're working with private Blockchain(PoA, 2 consensus node) and we've already created few blocks. Now we'd like to add some change in genesis file. So, basically question is, how can we support previous chain, also new blocks should be generated on basis of updated genesis file.

Could we use hard fork over private chain? if yes then how will it helps in our case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don' think you can do that. After creating the `genesis` block, it can't be changed unless you trash the whole blockchain. Forking will not resolve the issue because it will always have at least one block from the original chain.

If you fork form the genesis block, you will also be trashing the chain's data. thus those few blocks you crated.

Answer (score 1):

You are challenging the idea for which Bitcoin is now worth 6k USD. The whole point of cryptocurrencies is that once the genesis block has been created, everyone is going to agree that it is never going to change. It is like ADN of species that dictates the creation of a living being, you create it once and the whole blockchains grows from there. You know that you are using an Ethereum blockchain only because the genesis block's hash is 0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3

In your case, just delete the whole blockchain and start all over again.